# What's required to sell a home owned contract-for-deed that was previously owned by a person now represented by a conservatorship?

Tags: real-estate

One party has owned a home for several years contract-for-deed in Minnesota. The previous owner has in the interim become involved in a conservatorship (due to declining mental health), represented by the current owner and siblings. The current owner wishes to sell.

What is required normally of the previous owner in a contract-for-deed sale at closing, and what additional requirements does the conservatorship impose? How might the process be expedited to accommodate an impending closing date?

I attempted to add *contract-for-deed* and *conservatorship* to the tags array, but neither exist. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: A location (US? state? county?) might be needed as the jurisdiction may have limits on what a conservator can do.

Comment: Is it Minnesota? See https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/?id=524.5-418

Comment: Yes, Minnesota. Thank you for finding the appropriate document. I guess I'm wondering if a hearing is always called for, especially given that the home was technically sold 8 years ago, before the conservatorship was enacted.

Comment: If the contract hasn't been fulfilled, the current "owner" doesn't own the house yet. It looks to me to be a big conflict-of-interest and should definitely go through the usual court proceedings.